# MS accessUsing 2 foreign keys and allow only subset of another foreign key

Tags: database, ms-access, foreign-keys, ms-access-2007

I am using MS access to build relationship between 3 tables. I am only listing important columns

Table A has primary key akey

Table B has primary key bkey and foreign key from **Table A akey** as AF

Table C has primary key ckey and 2 more columns AC and BC.

AC is foreign key from akey(Table A). BC is foreign key from Table B bkey.

BC is optional field. So if BC is filled, only those values from bkey must be allowed that have AF equal to AC.

Any idea how to build this relationship?

Answer (score 0):

First, keep your attribute names consistent throughout your schema e.g. don't rename `akey` based on what table it is used in but instead use the name `akey` in all tables where it is used.

Second, avoid 'optional' columns, SQL nulls aren't worth all the bother. My suggested alternative approach is to use a forth table (a second `C` table named `C2`) for the optional relationship i.e. if there is a value for `( ckey, akey )` but no value for `( ckey, bkey )` then insert a row into `C` and none into `C2`.

Following the two above common-sense suggestions, the schema becomes fairly simply (yes, columns do get repeated but are required to be able to enforce the constraints and are therefore not redundant - you can 'query them away' using a `VIEW`):

```
CREATE TABLE A 
( 
 akey INT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE B 
( 
 bkey INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 akey INT NOT NULL REFERENCES A ( akey ),
 UNIQUE ( bkey, akey )
);

CREATE TABLE C
(
 ckey INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 akey INT NOT NULL REFERENCES A ( akey ),
 UNIQUE ( ckey, akey )
);

CREATE TABLE C2
(
 ckey INT NOT NULL,
 akey INT NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY ( ckey, akey ) REFERENCES C ( ckey, akey ),
 bkey INT NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY ( bkey, akey ) REFERENCES B ( bkey, akey ),
 UNIQUE ( ckey, akey, bkey )
);
```